# Select all checkbox not triggering their individual .change functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a checkbox on each row, plus a header checkbox that lets you select them all, that works fine with this code :

```js
var idArray = [];

$(function(event, request, settings){

    //This method is explained later in the post
    //It takes care of storing checked rows into an array
    setupStoreSelected();

    $(function(){
        //Get every checkbox in table body 
        var $checkboxes = $("tbody").find(":checkbox");

        //When checkAll is clicked, check/uncheck every enabled checkbox
        $("#checkAll").on("click", function(){
            $($checkboxes).not(":disabled").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });

        //Uncheck global if any individual checkbox is unchecked
        $("tbody").on("change", function () {
            if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                $("#checkAll").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    }); 
});

function setupStoreSelected(){

    //This selector listens to every checkbox except for the CheckAll
    $("input:checkbox:not('#checkAll')").change(function(){
        //Get that row's ID value from its column 
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.idColumn").text();

        //If it is checked now, push that ID into a global array
        if($(this).prop("checked")){
            idArray.push(id);
            console.log("Added ID : " + id);
        }

        //Search and delete it from array if it gets unchecked
        else{
            var index = idArray.indexOf(id);
            if(index > -1){
                idArray.splice(index,1);
                console.log("Deleted ID : " + id);
            }           
        }   
    });
}
```

```css
table{
  border : 1px solid grey;
}

thead{
  background-color : silver;
}

td{
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" width="20%">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="false"></th>

   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="idColumn">001</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="idColumn">002</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="idColumn">003</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="idColumn">004</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

The problem is that the `checkAll` checkbox does not trigger the `.change(...)` function of the individual checkboxes, so it doesnt work at all.

How can i modify my code so both individual and checkAll checkboxes store the ID's??

Comment: Try this: $($checkboxes).not(":disabled").prop('checked', 'checked'); instead of $($checkboxes).not(":disabled").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));. Otherwise, could you do a codepen?

Comment: @iMacAnge i will try to create a small version of it and add it to the post

Comment: @iMacAnge just uploaded a Snippet, plus, a CodePen : https://codepen.io/apokkalypsys/pen/QRVrvj?editors=1010

Comment: Oh wow, I add totally misunderstood your original question. I might not have fixed it the way you want it but why don't you just add something inside your `#checkAll listener`? Something like: `$("#checkAll").on("click", function(){
            $($checkboxes).not(":disabled").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            console.log($("tr").find("td.idColumn").text())
        });` And instead of the console.log you'll do a loop since it anyway selects everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this is the way i got it to work :

```js
var idArray = [];

$(document).on('change', '#checkAll', function(e) {
        var checkboxes = $('tbody').find(':checkbox').not(":disabled");
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
   checkboxes.each(
    function() {
     checkTerminal($(this).closest("tr").find("td.idColumn").text());  
    }
   );
  } else {
   checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
   checkboxes.each(
    function() {
     uncheckTerminal($(this).closest("tr").find("td.idColumn").text());   
    }
   );
  }
 });

 $(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.idColumn").text();
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   checkTerminal(id);
  } else {
   uncheckTerminal(id);
  }
  
 });

function checkTerminal(id){
    if((idArray.indexOf(id) == -1) && (id!="") && (id!=null)){
        idArray.push(id);
        console.log("Adding ID : " + id);
    }
    
}

function uncheckTerminal(id){
    var index = idArray.indexOf(id);
 if((index != -1) && (id!="") && (id!=null)){
  idArray.splice(index,1);
  console.log("Deleting ID : " + id);
 } 
}
```

```css
table{
    border : 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  thead{
    background-color : silver;
  }
  
  td{
    text-align : center;
  }
  
  *{
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" width="20%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="false"></th>
    
                </tr>
            </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="idColumn">001</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="idColumn">002</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="idColumn">003</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="idColumn">004</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a change event for all individual check boxes using `trigger('change')` as:

```
//When checkAll is clicked, check/uncheck every enabled checkbox
 $("#checkAll").on("click", function(){
      $($checkboxes).not(":disabled").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')).trigger('change');
 });
```

Comment: I tried your solution but for some reason, it disables the checkAll tick, and doesnt uncheck after that